# Finding the critical points of $f(x,y,z)=(x+y)^2+\frac{1}{(x+y)^2}+z^2-4z+2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I need help finding the critical points of function
$$f(x,y,z)=(x+y)^2+\frac{1}{(x+y)^2}+z^2-4z+2$$

So far from the first derivatives I figured out that $z=2$, but for $x$ and $y$ I get $x+y=1$.

How do I proceed with the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a mistake somewhere. Since$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y,z)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y,z)=2 (x+y)-\frac{2}{(x+y)^3}\text{ and }\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y,z)=2z-4,$$the critical points are those points $(x,y,2)$ such that $x+y=1$ *or* that $x+y=-1$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! True, I missed out on x+y=−1, but this solution then means I have an infinite number of critical points? And what if I need to tell, whether they are minimums, maximums or saddle points?

Comment: If $(x,y,z)\in\Bbb R^3$,$$f(x,y,z)=\left(x+y-\frac1{x+y}\right)^2+(z-2)^2,$$which takes the value $0$ when $x+y=\pm1$ and $z=2$ and which is greater than $0$ otherwise. So, all those points are minimums.